# image with overflow: hidden within container-fluid --does not hide image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Problem: img {Overflow: hidden;} isn't working as expected.

```
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
.container-fluid { 
  background-color: #092876;
  color: white;
  overflow:hidden;    <!-- change visible to hidden to see effect -->
  margin: 1% 5% 1% 5%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

</style>


<html>
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- container-fluid-->

<div class="about-me" id="about-me">  <!-- ABOUT ME SECTION-->
  <h1 class=about-me_h1>Lee Yang </h1>
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dsy2w1n70/image/upload/c_scale,h_461,w_450/v1492552203/p3_2_d3xydb.jpg" alt="Profile Picture"
       align=left>
  <p class=about-me_p1>If i remove hidden the picture renders outside of the element.  But if i use hidden, the element expands to capture the picture</p>



</div> <!--END of ABOUT ME SECTION-->
</html>
```

The element and the image are within a container-fluid.
If i remove overflow (default then set to visible), the image renders outside of the elements box; as expected.  But once I add overflow:hidden, the the element expands to cover the whole image.  This is what I want, but i stumbled upon this by accident fully expecting overflow:hidden to hide the latter part of the image.

Comment: What is the behaviour you expect/want in this case?

Comment: I want the element to stretch to fit the picture.  Overflow:hidden does that in the code, but I wasn't expecting it to.  I was expecting it to hide parts of the picture that rendered beyond the element borders, but instead it extended the element to fit the picture.  

Even though I'm getting what I want, I'm wondering why its doing that, and it might have something to do with container-fluid.